Pump fun bonding curve real time data updates
I'm writing a script using Js to buy tokens on pump fun. My issue is I need an API/endpoint that can update the market cap of each token that are still on the bonding curve on pump.fun. I can only get the updated market cap once the pump.fun tokens hits raydium. The script logs all the new tokens but I just want to also update the data of each token logged.

First thought would be use a solana rpc api to get token supply and then multiply it by the token price.
